# Requests to /page'A=0 in nginx error logs

Tags: nginx, http, firefox

I've been receiving error log entries of attempts to access various pages though my web server that just append `'A=0` at the end of the URL (e.g. `/about'A=0`). Upon closer inspection of my access log I found out that the request was apparently sent from Windows XP using Firefox 3.5.2 (built in 2009), but user agent headers can of course be faked.

I looked around on the Internet but apart from [a thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1973913) made by someone who was also concerned about these requests I found no further information about the URL parameter or it's intended (mis)use-case. Is this an attempt to breach my server by exploiting some known bug, or just an innocent mistake by the browser being used?

Comment: Welcome to the Internet! For public facing servers, you should expect to find (tens of? hundreds of?) thousands of hits to your server looking for various vulnerabilities every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33867813/4300531

Answers suggest it's a bot trying to find SQL injection vulnerabilities.